# Processing URL parameters

Tags: php, html, apache, htdocs

Im building a custom site with PHP, and its almost like a CMS, here I will have categories, subcategories and pages/posts, so my expected URL is like

```
mysite.com/category/sub-category/page-name/
```

and this hierarchy is not constant, I may get 3 or more subcategories, and I will also have pagination parameters in same URL like

```
mysite.com/category/sub-category/page-name/6
```

So, in my site index.php will only handle all the URLs as like in other CMS, but Im not sure how to split this url and how to know which is page name, which pagination param, which is category parameter and all, please help me in achieving this.

Comment: Take a look at one of the simpler PHP Frameworks, like `CodeIgniter` for example. Either use one of those or see how they make those exact decisions. Bsaically you have to know that you will always start with the most significant parameter i.e. Category and work left to right towards the least significant parameter.

Comment: Use `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` to get the filename of the currently executing script.

Comment: @joke : Hi, Index.php will the file responsible and it will include all other required files into it, and its not about script name, just want to know how to proces urls, like in RiggsFolly said, how CodeIgnitor is processing URLs, or how WP is doing it?

Answer (score 0):

What you are after is known as a "front controller", a single PHP file that handles every request coming into your application.

As mentioned by RiggsFolly, most PHP frameworks have this built into them.  Here is the front controller for Symfony (my fav PHP framework)

```
// index.php
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$path = $request->getPathInfo(); // the URI path being requested

if (in_array($path, array('', '/'))) {
    $response = new Response('Welcome to the homepage.');
} elseif ($path == '/contact') {
    $response = new Response('Contact us');
} else {
    $response = new Response('Page not found.', 404);
}
$response->send();
```

Comment: Thanks, but if have only one value on URL I can go like this, and its doens matter in my script to proceed single value like domain.com/my-page, but probably it will contain many things, category hierarchy details, may be some date of post structure like Wp or some pagination page numbers after url

Comment: The above code deals with that.  Simply add an extra "elseif" for each route you get.